# Magento 2 EE remove url trailing slash through htaccess

Tags: magento2, url, htaccess

I am using below code in htaccess to remove trailing slash in urls. But after adding this code my admin panel stops working and shows error - Too many redirects. 
I don't know whether to place this code within any IfModule block or not.

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please provide a solution.